# SceneKit not infinite node with material properties of floor node

Tags: scenekit

I am trying to add reflective floors to my scene. The built in floor node is perfect in terms of looks. It does exactly what I want. The issue arises because I don't want it to be infinite. I want to give my scene multiple floors with gaps in-between them. I think the word platform better describes them.

Anyways I am looking for one of two solutions:

A) a way to make the standard floor node non infinite

Or

B) a way to make the standard box node have the material/reflective properties of a the standard floor node

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting iOS 10 and macOS 10.12 the `SCNFloor` class has [`width`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnfloor/1845280-width) and [`length`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnfloor/2091890-length) properties that allow for non-infinite floors.

Comment: Knew there had to be a simple way I was missing, thanks so much